# Microsoft Graph API: DELETE / PATCH Event Instances

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

As seen [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/event_list_instances), it's possible to send a GET request and get the event *instances*. I need to send DELETE and PATCH requests also, is this possible and if so, how? It's not documented and I couldn't find a similar question. I'm referring specifically to the event instances and not the upper level events / occurrences.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried issuing the `PATCH` or `DELETE` against Instance's id? I believe the intended behavior is if an Instance is deleted it becomes an exception of the Series Master and if a Series Master is deleted then every Instance gets deleted along with it.

Comment: I can confirm that's how it works. Which is why I need the ability to delete and patch single instances, so I can create exceptions and instances where needed. I've been tried to PATCH and DELETE them, to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question properly, **you'd like to be able to make updates to instances of a recurring event**, but not the whole series/main event.
This is possible, you first need to get the instance id by [querying the instances of the event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-list-instances?view=graph-rest-1.0) (each event that displays on the calendar has it's own id).
Once you have the event id, you can use the [regular endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0) to update that specific instance.
*Note: all events instances have `seriesMasterId` property to identify the parent event object.

Note: Updating the main event (the one with the regular pattern) will reset changes to instances.*

Comment: But how do I know which parameters I will use to query? Like, change notification is only giving me seriesMasterId. Not even start and end date of that specific instance. So, how am I supposed to know which instance I will be changing?